# How to Use Unique Variable for every user to pass values through pages in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, variables

I want to pass a value through pages so i tried with Application variable. But problem is variable is not unique for every user so value gets compromised.

Session Variable is used to create session and it works perfect.
I dont want to create session... i want to pass another value through each session and the value will differ according to user.

**Here i create session for every faculty Logs in. And according to each faculty his schoolname is identified and transferred it to faculty welcome page.**

```
if (pass == txtFacPass.Text && schoolName == listFacSch.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                Session["fac"] = txtFacUser.Text;
                Application["sname"] = listFacSch.SelectedItem.ToString();
                Response.Redirect("faculty.aspx", false);
            }
```

Please help me with the solution ASAP. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: I dont want to create session... i want to pass another value through each session and the value will differ according to user.

Comment: Now I totally not understand what do you try to do.

Comment: @Aristos I have edited the question now. Please see if u can help with it !

Comment: Still do not understand what you try to do. Can you please say what you try to do (and leave the session, application and parameters away ?)

Comment: @Aristos Yes i have edited again Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to pass two values to `faculty.aspx`, the user name and the school name.

You are already passing the user name through the session:

```
Session["fac"] = txtFacUser.Text;
```

To pass another value just store it using a different key:

```
Session["sname"] = listFacSch.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

This will **not** cause another session to be created. Both values will be available in the other page in the one session created for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Application variables are for each Application, not each user. so you are just resetting a single value every time.

If I understand what you are trying to do, why dont you just use URI parameters,

```
Response.Redirect("faculty.aspx?sname=" + listFacSch.SelectedItem.ToString() , false);
```

and then handle the query string parameter on the faculty page 
(assuming you are displaying different things for different schools)

Comment: Thank You but query string reveals the information and it can be tampered. Thank u though !

Comment: ah, I was not aware that you did not know that you can create multiple session variables in the same session

Comment: @e wagness Thanx anyways :) ;)